# Display city with second highest number of stores in sql

Tags: sql

Display city with second highest number of stores.

here is table toy_store with data IN IMAGE[TOY_STORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl9fq.png)

Comment: You should check out the [docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what makes a good question. I'd also suggest (for your own benefit) that you edit this question adding more detail of what you want and showing some code of what you've tried already.

Comment: I tried lot of methods using group by and having clause to filter max row, but couldn't get the accurate SQL method to fetch second highest row. Further I was new to this stack community so made errors in posting question.

Answer (score 3):

Remember this is not service to complete your assignments, you should try it first, show some efforts, for now you could get ans for you question and there are number of way to do this.

```
SELECT TOP(1),* 
FROM
( 
   SELECT TOP(2) CITY,COUNT(CITY)
   FROM TableName
   GROUP BY CITY
   ORDER BY CITY DESC
)M
```

Comment: Thanks, have tried those assignments but couldn't get the solution so asked here.

Answer (score 0):

The question as I and @jaydip-jadhav have mentioned lacks details. It's also very old at this point but since it came back up via your comments I decided to take another look.

However, the above should work with minimal changes depending on what you're using (again, more details would help such as what DBMS your using and what version, etc).

That said you could also google what you're after and find a variety of solutions.

### An Example solution

But here's 2 working basic examples **you can view, run and use with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e19a1d/80)**.

If the fiddle stops working here's the details you could use to recreate on your own somewhere.

This is using `MySQL 5.6` (old, but so's this question).

#### Schema based on your image (next time, type it out):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `toy_store` (
  `toy_store_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `toy_store_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `store_opening_time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `store_closing_time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`toy_store_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `toy_store` (`toy_store_id`, `toy_store_name`, `city`, `phone_number`, `store_opening_time`, `store_closing_time`) VALUES
  ('1', 'kids cave', 'Delhi', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('2', 'kids corner', 'Mumbai', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('3', 'play and grow', 'Mumbai', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('4', 'puzzles and more', 'Delhi', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('5', 'uncle same toys den', 'Delhi', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('6', 'mickey toys', 'Delhi', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05'),
  ('7', 'mickey toys', 'Somewhere Else', '9912312312', '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

#### 2 basic queries that work against the above schema:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT city, count(city) as count_city 
  FROM toy_store 
  GROUP BY city 
  ORDER BY COUNT(city) desc 
  LIMIT 2
) as top2 
ORDER BY top2.count_city asc
LIMIT 1;


  -- RESULT
  -- city       count_city
  -- Mumbai     2


SELECT DISTINCT city, count(city) as count_city
FROM toy_store 
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY COUNT(city) 
LIMIT 1,1;

  -- RESULT
  -- city       count_city
  -- Mumbai     2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already got the solution.