# Second highest value from Oracle DB's table

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

According to the tables:

```
USERS (user_name, email, balance)
```

How can I create a query that return the second highest user balance in the most **efficient** way ?

I successes to get this record (but not by the efficient way) with the query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM  
  (SELECT 
    us.*,
    ROWNUM row_num
  FROM  
    (SELECT 
      u.*
    FROM
      users u
    ORDER BY
      u.BALANCE DESC) us
  WHERE
    ROWNUM < 3)
WHERE
  row_num > 1;
```

Comment: You may get some idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990303/display-city-with-second-highest-number-of-stores-in-sql/38990690#38990690

Comment: What do you want returned if there are ties for the highest value?

Comment: Your code is fine, assuming you have an index on `users(Balance)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select u.*, dense_rank() over (order by balance desc) as rnk
  from users u
) t
where rnk = 2;
```

I don't think there will be a big performance difference to your query (especially not with an index on `balance`) but in my opinion it's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: suggestion: instead of dense_rank() better to use row_number()

Comment: @Aishu: but that wouldn't return multiple users with the same balance that is the second highest. It would only return a single user even if there is another one with the same (second highest) balance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *   
      FROM USERS   
      ORDER BY balance DESC  
      FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
      ) 
ORDER BY balance DESC  
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: It'll be nice to compare this 2 methods. Probably this one is faster.

Comment: Keep in mind that if OP wants duplicates he should use `WITH TIES`

Answer (score 0):

This should work even in case of more than one user having same 2nd largest balance..

```
select * from USERS where balance IN
  (select max(balance) 
     from (select balance from USERS 
    where balance NOT IN (select max(balance) from USERS))
);
```